# Unable to get file list from standard resource dir in Maven project with Spring PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver

Tags: java, spring, maven, resources, classpath

NOTE: As per the accepted solution below, this appears to be realated only to the fact that Spring's DefaultResourceLoader does not use the classloader to create URL instances for resources, thus custom classloaders are ignored

https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-8176

I have a standard Maven project, it looks something like this

```
$ tree
.
├── pom.xml
└── src
    ├── main
    │   ├── java
    │   │   
    │   └── resources
    │       └── application.properties
    └── test
        └── java
```

I will have more resource files shortly in a directory tree under the resources directory, and I would like to loop over them.  Following several other posts, I am using the `PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver` from the Spring Framework.  The function I have written to grab all file names is as follows

```
public static List<File> getAllResourceFiles() {
    PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver resolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();
    Resource[] resources;
    try {
        resources = resolver.getResources("classpath*:.*");
        System.out.println(JsonUtils.objectToJson(resources));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Where `objectToJson` is a function that simply uses Jackson to serialize an object. Now when I compile and run this application, I do not get any results.  In particular, I do not see application.properties.  How do I make this work?

```
$ java -jar target/MyApp.one-jar.jar
[]
```

UPDATE: As noted in the comment below, this is using Simon Tuffs' one jar maven plugin.  However, the usual way of reading files from the classpath works.  Namely

```
MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/application.properties");
```

UPDATE 2: I tried the following:

```
resources = resolver.getResources("classpath:**/*.*");
```

And get this stack trace

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getURL(ClassPathResource.java:178)
at org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.isJarResource(PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.java:414)
at org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.findPathMatchingResources(PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.java:343)
at org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.getResources(PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.java:282)
at com.example.utils.ResourceUtils.getAllResourceFiles(ResourceUtils.java:29)
at com.example.Starter.main(Starter.java:14)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.simontuffs.onejar.Boot.run(Boot.java:340)
at com.simontuffs.onejar.Boot.main(Boot.java:166)
```

The code in Starter.java is

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 
    System.out.println(Environment.getProperty("com.example.applicationLogPath"));
    System.out.println(JsonUtils.objectToJson(ResourceUtils.getAllResourceFiles()));
}
```

The first line executes successfully and prints the string value of the applicationLogPath property.  The second causes the FNF stack trace.  The code to get the property uses the standard method for getting an input stream to a file in the jar.

```
Environment.class.getResourceAsStream("/application.properties");
```

Comment: That folder structure is packed inside MyApp.jar? Or better said, relative to MyApp.jar location where is application.properties?

Comment: Thats a great question, I am using the maven jar plugin and the one jar plugin.  I looked inside the jar `jar tvf target/MyApp.one-jar.jar` and I see `main/MyApp.jar` when I extract the contents of the jar, and look into this jar`$ jar tvf MyApp.jar` I see `application.properties` at the top level.

Comment: That said, I am able to extract a specific resource, as in `InputStream inputStream = MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/application.properties");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is with OneJar. Your project runs just fine if it's used outside the "one-jar" jar, I've tested it (after I commented the JsonUtils parts which were breaking) and I can see the files it's scanning. And it seems [others have hit this or similar issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-8176), as well. Also, I am not so sure Spring (through that JIRA issue) will be changed so that the resources will be loaded to please OneJar.

Comment: Oh that's interesting, I see, so that explains why the normal call to class.getResourceAsStream is successful.

Comment: ^ but mechanisms to list the contents are not.

Comment: I added the relevent jars to my classpath and ran without the onejar plugin, i still get this `java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
 at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getURL(ClassPathResource.java:178)
 at ...`  Any ideas?  I think Im getting tired of trying to use spring for this

Comment: You're right. I made a mistake. The files that were printed on the console were from the directory were the executable jar was launched not from within the jar itself.

Answer (score 1):

What I think you're looking for is

```
resources = resolver.getResources("classpath:**/*.*");
                                        // ^ don't need the * here
```

which matches every resource in any nested level with any extension.

What you have

```
resources = resolver.getResources("classpath*:.*");
```

matches resources at the root of the classpath with no name but any extension.

Comment: Hi Sotirios, thanks for the reply.  I tried that but I am still getting `java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist`  And I am still able to get the contents of the application.properties directly via `MyApp.class.getResourceAsStream("/application.properties");`  When I add the asterisk to the classpath as in `resources = resolver.getResources("classpath*:**/*.*");` I do not get the FNF exception but the results are still empty (ie application.properties).

Comment: @DavidWilliams Can you edit in your question exactly what you tried after my answer? Also post any stack trace that gets printed.

Comment: @DavidWilliams What's on the classpath of the jar?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  This is a fat jar, so I haven't included anything from outside the jar.  Do I understand your question correctly?

Comment: @DavidWilliams The error message you've shown seems to indicate that for whatever reason, the resolver created a resource with an empty path. I don't see how that could happen. How are you currently running your application?

Comment: Can I ask you to indulge me for a moment in running it?  It is on github and compiles with maven.  https://github.com/mobiusinversion/EtymologyDynamics  it is just the beginning of a natural language processing application wherein I would like to store some data in the resources directory for internal application usage.  The compilation and execution model is very simple `mvn clean package && java -jar target/EtymologyDynamics.one-jar.jar`

Comment: @DavidWilliams I don't have much time now, but it seems like your `OneJar` configuration (I don't exactly know what it does), but it doesn't seem to load classes correctly.

Comment: @DavidWilliams Try running your code in eclispe (or other IDE) directly instead of going through the jar.

Comment: Yep, thats whats going on, Andrei found a Spring Jira about this too (below)